# Certificate Error on dropping www from https://www.example.com

Tags: iis, load-balancing, ssl-certificate, https, website

I was looking at this [blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/the-great-dub-dub-dub-debate.html) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355217/should-i-default-my-website-to-www-foo-or-not) These things prefer to drop www from their websites. But if you are running a website on SSL and you drop www, won't you get a certificate error? I use wild card cert on all my websites. Few examples:

https://something.example.com

https://somethingelse.example.com

https://www.example.com (this is the website I want to drop www)

If I do that I will get a certificate error when I access the website any browser, how can I fix this?

Comment: The SSL certificates I get from GoDaddy work on both www and non-www. Sometimes we receive SSL certs from other vendors that don't work this way, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the non-www name as a valid subject name in your certificate.  Many CAs will put `example.com` in the subject alternate names field when issuing a certificate for `www.example.com` (or for `*.example.com`, in the wildcard case), but it sounds like your certificate doesn't have this.

You likely need to obtain a new certificate to cover both names.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a certificate for `example.com`, and publish `example.com` on another IP.

A wildcard certificate for `*.example.com` will match any direct subdomain to `example.com` but never `example.com` itself, unless it's included as a SAN.

Alternatively, have users redirected to `ssl.example.com` or `secure.example.com` or alike, when they need encryption, and otherwise use `example.com` only over HTTP

An example: You run a blog or social site. Have content accessible on HTTP, but when users need access to login forms, settings pages or the likes, link to `https://ssl.example.com/login.php`